# phase, magnitude, audio file and information

Tags: fft, audio, phase, magnitude

I've been doing some thinking lately. I know that for image files a larger portion of information is contained in the phase of the signal. How does that go for the audio? Does the same hold or is the amplitude the one with the more information content? Thx all.

Comment: most of the time we're not as concerned for phase in audio as you might be in some phase-coherent context.  like communications and, as you say, for image processing.

Comment: Phase is relatively unimportant except that we use it indirectly to determine the direction of a sound source (difference of arrival time at each ear).

Comment: "for image [files] a larger portion of information is contained in the phase of the signal": images are essentially aperiodic and I really doubt that the human brains works in the Fourier space. (Wavelet-like analysis is more likely.)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments said. "monoaural phase" is not very important and monoaural phase changes are often inaudible. "binaural" phase is very important for localisation and imaging, particularly in stereo files.

"monoaural" means the phase of a single channel or that the same phase shift or modification is applied to all channels the same way.

"binaural" means specifically the difference in the signal at the left and the right ear.

Answer (score 1):

Audio for humans?  The human ear-brain system appears to be insensitive to absolute phase within stationary pitches, but more sensitive or responsive to differential phase (between the two ears), periodic or patterned changes in phase (pitch modulations), and perhaps phase coincidence within the spectrum to help characterize transient envelopes.

Animals that use echo location to hunt their meals may be far more sensitive to the absolute phase of audio signals (both emitted and heard).